# Why does the view page reload when the button is clicked even after the RefreshView has been added?

Tags: views, forms, 9

#### Problem:

The View page is reloaded when clicking on the buttons even after adding **RefreshView**:

```
 (function($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.switchContentViewMode = {
    attach: function attach(context) {
      $('.product-list-wrapper .wrapper-buttons button', context).each(function () {
        $(this).on('click', function () {
          let $exposedForm = $('#views-exposed-form-list-of-products-page-1');
          $exposedForm.find('.view_mode_changer').attr('value', $(this).attr('value'));
          $exposedForm.submit();
    
           // Added RefreshView so that the view page does not reload after a click:
          $.each(Drupal.views.instances, function (index, element) {
            if (element.settings.view_name == 'list_of_products') {
              element.settings.view_args = $(this).attr('value');
              $('.js-view-dom-id-' + element.settings.view_dom_id).trigger('RefreshView');
            }
          });

        })
      });
    }
  };
```

Did I make a mistake somewhere in the code? Or **RefreshView** will not help me, in this case, to prevent the page from reloading and should I do something differently?

---

#### More details:

##### A task:

I needed to make two buttons on the view page that changed the view mode in the view.

1. The **Grid** button changes view mode to **product_card_frontpage** where three product cards are placed in one row on the page (in the default settings in the View, this view mode)
2. The **List** button changes view mode to **product_card_full_width** where three product cards are placed in one row on the page and an additional field appears in the card.

##### I have implemented it like this:

1. In the View settings, set Use Ajax
2. Created two buttons in the twig view template:

```
<button value="product_card_frontpage" class="grid-view">Grid</button>
<button value="product_card_full_width" class="list-view">List</button>
```

3. Added a hidden **view_mode_changer** field to the exposed view form:

```
  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form' && $form_state->getStorage('view')['view']->id() == 'list_of_products') {
    $form['view_mode_changer'] = [
      '#type' => 'hidden',
      '#value' => 'product_card_frontpage',
      '#attributes' => [
        'class' => ['view_mode_changer'],
      ],
    ];
  }
```

4. When clicking on the buttons, I change the value of the **view_mode_changer** field:

```
 (function($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.switchContentViewMode = {
    attach: function attach(context) {
      $('.product-list-wrapper .wrapper-buttons button', context).each(function () {
        $(this).on('click', function () {
          let $exposedForm = $('#views-exposed-form-list-of-products-page-1');
          $exposedForm.find('.view_mode_changer').attr('value', $(this).attr('value'));
          $exposedForm.submit();
    
           // Added RefreshView so that the view page does not reload after a click:
          $.each(Drupal.views.instances, function (index, element) {
            if (element.settings.view_name == 'list_of_products') {
              element.settings.view_args = $(this).attr('value');
              $('.js-view-dom-id-' + element.settings.view_dom_id).trigger('RefreshView');
            }
          });

        })
      });
    }
  };
```

5. Using `hook_views_pre_view()` I change the view mode:

```
function entity_product_admin_views_pre_view(ViewExecutable $view, $display_id, array &$args) {
  if ($view->id() == 'list_of_products') {
    $row_options = $view->display_handler->getOption('row');
    $row_options['options']['view_mode'] = $view->getExposedInput()['view_mode_changer'] ?? 'product_card_frontpage';
    $view->display_handler->overrideOption('row', $row_options);
  }
```

Comment: `<button>`s submit the form they're in, so you need to prevent the default event from firing. Change your click handler to `$(this).on('click', function (e) {`, and add `e.preventDefault()` in the function body

Comment: @Clive I added ```e.preventDefault();``` See screenshot: https://ibb.co/DrHzxzN
But the page still reloads. And what's interesting when reloading to the standard path:
```http://mywebsite/list```
is added:
```http://mywebsite/list?view_mode_changer=product_card_full_width```

I'm thinking, maybe the reason for the reload is related to this line in the hook_views_pre_view () hook:
```$row_options['options']['view_mode'] = $view->getExposedInput()['view_mode_changer'] ?? 'product_card_frontpage';
```

Comment: @Clive And maybe something else needs to be put in ```$row_options['options']['view_mode']``` ?